# Animating several elements at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I saw another post on here saying this would work - and it's definitely not. Wondering why these are not all executing at once?

I am simply trying to get the `top` and `opacity` animations to happen at once. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DU8N2/

```
$(".wordcar").animate({
       top:"32px"
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
    $(".wordcar li.next").animate({
       opacity:"1"
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
    $(".wordcar li.current").animate({
       opacity:"0.2"
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
     $(".wordcar li.ondeck").animate({
       opacity:"0.2"
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
     $(".wordcar li.previous").animate({
       opacity:"0.0"
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
```

Comment: `wordcar` encapsulates the four other elements, but you can see that those four elements are animating at once after the div. Maybe try removing the need for the div container.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in a queue. Try setting the `fade` animations `duration: 1000`, instead of 2000 and there you have your magic.